# SQL query to select students who have taken all subjects from subjects table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `student_records` and `subjects`. I have to find out those students who have taken all the subjects (1,2,3) from the subjects table.
[image]

```sql
create table subject (ID int primary key, subject varchar(50));
insert into subject values (1,'English'),(2,'Bengali'),(3,'Math');
create table student_records(ID int primary key,student_id int , sub_id int,foreign key (sub_id) 
references subject(ID));
insert into student_records values (1,1,1),(2,3,2),(3,1,3),(4,1,2),(5,2,1),(6,3,3),(7,3,1),(8,4,1);

/*select *from student_records;
select *from subject;*/
```

I have done with this

```sql
select student_id from student_records
    group by student_id
    having count(*)=(select count(*) from subject);
```

Is there any better query?

Comment: Why doo you want/need a "better way" ? Is this one not good enough ? (BTW: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=962068e08bdc1dc2249555f4602ad018))

Comment: Looks perfect to me. (There should be a unique constraint on `student_records(student_id, subject_id)`  of course to guarantee this to work properly.)

Comment: The answer provided by vtan707 is better I think. It solves my purpose. Thanks @Luuk .

Comment: @Pranto: "The purpose you wanted to solve"  was/is not clear. I am glad that someone wrote a solution that is not "better", and solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a "better" way, but I would make sure to use count distinct in this case:

```
SELECT
    student_id
    ,COUNT( distinct  sub_id) AS subject_cnt
FROM student_records
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING subject_cnt = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subject
```